# In Common Lisp, how would you extend the existing comparator operations to work for new types?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm attempting to implement a lisp version of a domain specific language that uses the binary operators and comparators on discrete probability distributions. Is there a safe(ish) and concise way to extend the functionality of these atoms `< <= = >= > + - / *` to work with new types, without completely bricking the language?

I realize just making new operator names would be the easiest solution, but that answer is not compelling nor fun, and certainly doesn't live up to lisp's reputation as the programmable programming language.

For example, say we have the hash-table:

```lisp
((4 . 1/4) (3 . 1/4) (2 . 1/4) (1 . 1/4))
```

which we create with the macro `(d 4)`, and we want to be able to compare it to a number like so

```lisp
(< (d 4) 3)
```

which we would want to return a hash-table representing a 50% chance it's true and 50% chance it's false, say in this form:

```lisp
((0 . 1/2) (1 . 1/2))
```

but currently it produces the error:
`*** - <: #S(HASH-TABLE :TEST FASTHASH-EQL (4 . 1/4) (3 . 1/4) (2 . 1/4) (1 . 1/4)) is not a real number`

Comment: The built-in comparison functions are not generic functions that can be extended. You'll need to define your own generic functions.

Comment: Yes. Your generic functions can use the symbol names < <= = >= > + - / *, however, only in a different package, not the CL package: MYDSL:< MYDSL:<= MYDSL:= MYDSL:>= MYDSL:> etc. You'll need to use (powerful) Common Lisp mechanisms for exporting and shadowing symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three answers to this:

1. no, you can't do it because `+` &c are not generic functions in CL and you may not redefine symbols exported from the `CL` package ...
2. ... but yes, of course you can do it if you're willing to accept a small amount of inconvenience, because Lisp is a programmable programming language ...
3. ... but no, in fact you can't *completely* do it if you want to preserve the semantics of your extended language in fact, and there isn't anything you can do about that.

So let's look at these in order.

### (1): The arithmetic operators are not generic functions in CL ...

This means you can't extend them: they work on numbers.  And you can't redefine them because [the language forbids that](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_abab.htm).

### (2): ... but of course you can get around that ...

So, the first trick is we want to define a package in which the arithmetic operators are *not* the CL versions of them.  We can do this manually, but we'll use [Tim Bradshaw's conduits system](https://tfeb.github.io/conduit-packages/) to make life easier:

```
(in-package :org.tfeb.clc-user)

(defpackage :cl/generic-arith
  ;; The package people will use
  (:use)
  (:extends/excluding :cl
   #:< #:<= #:= #:= #:> #:+ #:- #:/ #:*)
  (:export
   #:< #:<= #:= #:= #:> #:+ #:- #:/ #:*))

(defpackage :cl/generic-arith/user
  ;; User package
  (:use :cl/generic-arith))

(defpackage :cl/generic-arith/impl
  ;; Implementation package
  (:use :cl/generic-arith))
```

So now:

```
> (in-package :cl/generic-arith/user)
#<The CL/GENERIC-ARITH/USER package, 0/16 internal, 0/16 external>

> (describe '*)

* is a symbol
name          "*"
value         #<unbound value>
function      #<unbound function>
plist         nil
package       #<The CL/GENERIC-ARITH package, 0/1024 internal, 978/1024 external>
```

So now we can get on with defining these things.  There are some problems: because what we've done is create an environment where, for instance `*` is not `cl:*`, then anything which uses `*` *as a symbol* will not work.  So for instance `cl:*` is bound the the value of the last form evaluated in the repl, and typing `*` isn't going to get that symbol: you'll need to type `cl:*`.

Similarly the [`+` method combination](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/07_ffd.htm) will not work: you'd have to explicitly say

```
(defgeneric foo (...)
  ...
  (:method-combination cl:+)
  ...)
```

So there is some pain.  But not, probably, that much pain.

And now we can start implementing things.  The obvious approach is to define generic functions which are 2-arg versions of the functions we need, and then define the functions on top of them.  That means we can use things like compiler macros for the actual operators without fear of breaking the underlying generic functions.

So start by

```
(in-package :cl/generic-arith/impl)

(defgeneric +/2 (a b)
  (:method ((a number) (b number))
   (cl:+ a b)))

...
```

And now you think for a bit and realise that ...

### (3) ... but there are problems you *can't* get around, in any language

The problem is at least this: `+` is one of the two operators on a field, and the way it is defined in `CL` in terms of some two-argument function like `+/2` above is something like this (this may be wrong implementationally but it's how the maths would go):

- `(+ a)` is `a`;
- `(+ a b)` is `(+/2 a b)`;
- `(+ a b ...)` is (+/2 a (+ b ...)` and this is fine by associativity (but beware of floats).

And that looks fine but we've missed a case:

- `(+)` is the additive identity of the field (and similarly `(*)` is the multiplicative identity).

Oh, wait: *what field*?  For `cl:+` this is fine: it's the identities of the field of numbers.  But now?  Who knows?  And there's nothing that can be done about that: if you want `+` to work the way it does in CL, except on other fields, you can't have that.

In general if `+` and `*` are to represent the two operations of a field, then if zero-argument versions of those operators are allowed those should return the two identities of the field (which they do in CL).  But that means that all fields they are defined for must share those two identities (which, again, they do in CL: the fields of rationals & complex numbers share identities).  This means in turn that `(+ x 3)` (from `(+ x (*) (*) (*))`) must be allowed (and so on).  Or you either disallow the zero-argument case, or that they represent the field operations, or both.

Comment: I don't understand your point 3 at all. What you do is define your own `+` function in your own package, which looks like this `(defun + (&rest args) ...)` and this performs a left reduction over the arguments using your generic `+`.

Comment: Try `(defun plus (&rest args) (reduce #'+ args :initial-value 0))`, and evaluate `(plus)`, `(plus 1)`, `(plus 1 2)`, `(plus 1 2 3)`.

Comment: @Kaz I have added a more detailed explanation of the zero-argument problem.  Indeed your very definition of `plus` (I do understand how to do that, thanks) encapsulates it: you have to wire in the zero of a specific field, which means this can never work for any field which does not share that zero.

Comment: I understand that, but the built in `+` has the same issue; it's also an N-ary operation (down to zero arguments) which is defined in terms of a left-to-right reduction over a binary operation, and it also has to pick a zero for the no-arguments case. In practical terms, we are in a dynamic language in which we can have a generic zero *symbol* that has the right interpretation in the places that we need it. So for instance if you're dealing with matrices, all your matrix methods can have `eql` specializations that recognize the integer `0` as a zero matrix of the necessary dimensions.

Comment: If `0` were confusing as the identity element, then, say, the `:zero` keyword could be used.  You could then have `(defmethod bin+ ((left mymatrix) (right (eql :zero))) left)` and so on.  Zero is just an abstraction which is why we can use the same English word "zero" to denote different kinds of zero in different fields.

Comment: @Kaz: you have not, in fact understood the problem (think about `(+ x (*) (*))` and what it means) but I'm not going to argue with you, least of all here.  Bye.

Comment: `(+ x (*) (*))` means `(+ (+ x (*)) (*)`, so let's focus on `(+ x (*))`.  `(*)` has no arguments, and we are supporting multiple kinds of fields, so we can have it return a universal multiplicative identity. That could be the symbol `:one`. Then if `x` is an integer, that becomes `1`. If `x` is a matrix, it becomes a suitably dimensioned identity matrix and so on.  There could be unsupported combinations which signal conditions. Since this is all in a custom package, you just design the rules to meet the application's requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can by using [generic-cl](https://github.com/alex-gutev/generic-cl/), that does that and that is extensible.

```lisp
(= "hello" y)  ;; would throw an error in standard CL
```

You would `:use` `:generic-cl` instead of `:cl` in a package definition, and you would use `:generic-cl-user` at the REPL.

Subclass the methods `equalp` and `lessp`.

Comment: And that's exactly the kind of half-thought-out horror I was worried about: if you have a list of <x> you should be able to assume that `(apply #'+ <list of <x>>)` is an <x>.  And with generic-cl, you can't assume that any more.

Comment: Why not, if I know I feed `apply` a list of <x> ? Also, it is only defined with numbers by default. So, I assume it is my responsibility to use objects that make sense with `+`.

Comment: I have added a paragraph to my answer which explains the field-identity problem.